# linq with viewbag data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, dropdown, viewbag

**Controller**

```
ViewBag.Subdivison = new SelectList(db.Retention_Model_Predictions_DS_Manual.Select(m => m.Underwriter_Name).Distinct(), "Underwriter_Name", "Underwriter_Name");
```

**View**

```
@Html.DropDownList("Underwriter_Name", null, "Please Select", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
```

**Error found in Controller**

> "Error = Unable to evaluate the expression. Operation not supported. Unknown error: 0x80070057."

**Error found in view**

> There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable' that has the key 'Underwriter_Name'.

Comment: The error in your controller is caused by the line you have written above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think

```
ViewBag.Subdivison = new SelectList(db.Retention_Model_Predictions_DS_Manual.Select(m => m.Underwriter_Name).Distinct(), "Underwriter_Name", "Underwriter_Name");
```

is the reason you're getting the error in your controller.

However, the error you're receiving in your view is because your ViewBag name is `Subdivison` but yet you're calling `Underwriter_Name` as the first parameter in your DropDownList method.

Change your View code to:

```
@Html.DropDownList("Subdivison", null, "Please Select", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
```

*You spelled subdivison wrong.. you're missing an 'i'.  Subdivision.*

Hope this helps.